# How to large amout of data to dynamic grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have to load a large amount of data to a dynamic grid view.  Grid view having link button created dynamically based on data.
While clicking the link button, Inner Grid should be loaded. It is working fine.

But every time, on clicking the link button, on the Row bound event is fired, to bind the main grid.

With in the row bound event, inner grid is loading for each row in main grid , which is already clicked. i have maintain the clicked link button state(id field of the particular row) in Session, and using the session value , loading the inner grid on each row in main grid which is matched the session value in row bound event.

But loading takes long time. Is any other way to binding data to dynamic grid view on clicking the link button and maintain the clicked link button inner grid ?

My code is

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{

    if (strCallTypeName[intLoop].ToLower() != "total")
    {
        LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
        lnk.Text = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataItem)).Row[strCallTypeName[intLoop]].ToString();
        lnk.CommandArgument = strCallTypeName[intLoop] 
            + "|||" 
            + ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataItem)).Row["UserId"].ToString() 
            + "|||" 
            + ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataItem)).Row["Service"].ToString() 
            + "|||" 
            + e.Row.RowIndex;

        //lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
        //lnk.CommandName = "Edit";
        lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lnk_Click);
        lnk.ToolTip = strCallTypeName[intLoop];
        lnk.CssClass = "lnk";
        tc.Controls.Add(lnk);

        string strUserID =grdSummaryCall.DataKeys[e.Row .RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        string strSessionUserDetails = string.Empty;
        strSessionUserDetails = (string)Session["GridUserDetails"];
        if (strSessionUserDetails != string.Empty && strSessionUserDetails !=null)
        {
            string[] strSplitUserDetails = strSessionUserDetails.Split(new string[] { "~" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            Panel pnlTable = (Panel)e.Row.FindControl("pnlTable");

            for (int i = 0; i < strSplitUserDetails.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] strUserDetails = strSplitUserDetails[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                if (strUserID == strUserDetails[1].ToString())
                {
                    if (pnlTable.Visible == false)
                    {
                        GetUserCallDetails(strUserDetails, e.Row);
                        pnlTable.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what *load large amount of data* means. Can you give us an idea of what is a large amount of date - record count, number of fields? And maybe some code on what you are doing. We cannot tell from this question what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back. I mean the count of records. I have more than 20000 records from my sql and bind 30 records for every page. On each row binding, i connected to sql and get that particular link button inner grid details. this process takes long time.

Answer (score 1):

Pooja, based on your comment above, I would make sure paging is working as expected and you are:

**1** - *only* loading 30 records at time for the current page, not all of them and rendering 
only 30.

**2** - *NOT* calling again the database layer for each row binding; You can load all details for every single row of the page at once (so no more than page size, in your case 30), when loading the data for the current page, so your database calls would go down to 1 per page not 1 + pagesize == 31 in your case.